# trying to have 2 methods where a user inputs 2 numbers, then its gets returned to the second method to check for error

Tags: c#, input, return, user-input

Create a prompt asking the user to input two integer values.
Create a custom method which takes the second number input and divides it by the first number input.
Your program should not crash if a divide by zero error occurs; instead, your program should display the specific error to the screen.
Be sure to run your program to verify that it executes without error(s). If there are errors, you better fix them if you want full credit for the assignment.

using System;

```
class Program
{
    public Main()
    {
        int x, y;
        Console.Write("Please Enter First Number : ");
        bool isNum1 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
        Console.Write("Please Enter Second Number : ");
        bool isNum2 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);

        Console.WriteLine(Divide(y, x));
    }

    public static int Divide(int y, int x)
    {
        int results = 0;
        try
        {
            results = x / y;
        }
        catch (ArithmeticException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
             "ArithmeticException Handler: {0}",
             e.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
             "Generic Exception Handler: {0}",
             e.ToString());
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to ask a question - `im lost` is not a question and not a problem we can solve.  That said, I would validate that the divisor is not zero at the point of input by evaluating those two `isNum` bools and acting on them.  I'd also tell the user which is which.

Comment: sorry ill fix it just getting frustrated, and won't post like that again

Comment: Hi @NickMobetta :), welcome! I think your question can be more clear, you could write something like: "Forcing user not to divide by 0 by asking again for input". Try to keep titles as short as possible. I proposed an answer, check it out below.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it using a while loop that forces the user not to divide by zero, like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x, y = 0;
        while(y == 0) {
            Console.Write("Please Enter First Number : ");
            bool isNum1 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
            Console.Write("Please Enter Second Number : ");
            bool isNum2 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);

            Console.WriteLine(Divide(y, x));
        }
    }
```

With this code every time that the user tries to divide by zero is forced to enter the numbers again. If you want you can make the user input again just the second number like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int x, y = 0;           
            Console.Write("Please Enter First Number : ");
            bool isNum1 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
        while(y == 0) {
            Console.Write("Please Enter Second Number : ");
            bool isNum2 = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);

            Console.WriteLine(Divide(y, x));
        }
```

Note that the initialization of y = 0 is very important, as it allows the code to enter the loop.